# How to fix a function that restarts itself 3 lines in after writing to a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am creating a simple login script using the csv library for my own educational value. When I use the function, `register();` after appending the login details to the file my code seems to restart itself at line 63:

```
password = input('Please enter your chosen password: ')
```

I have tried finding a similar issue (no success), I hazard a guess it is to do with my structure.

```
# login.py
""" Logs in reading from a CSV
    text file
    """

# Imports
import csv

# Functions
def reset_login_file():
    """ Resets the users.txt
        file
        """

    with open('users.txt', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        csv_writer.writerow(['Admin', 'password'])

def login():
    """ Checks users.txt and
        logs in
        """

    print('')

def check_for_name(name_chosen):
    """ Checks for name_chosen in
        users.txt
        """

    with open('users.txt', 'r', newline='') as check_csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(check_csvfile)

        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[0] == name_chosen:
                print('Name is taken, please try again!')
                register()
                break

def password_checker(password_chosen):
    """ Checks the password
        meets criteria
        """

    stop_loop = False
    while not stop_loop:
        if len(password_chosen) > 6 and len(password_chosen) < 13:
            print('Valid Password!')
            stop_loop = True
        else:
            print('Invalid Password, please try again!')
            register()
        break

def register():
    """ Registers the user in
        users.txt
        """

    username = input('Please enter your chosen username: ')
    check_for_name(username)
    password = input('Please enter your chosen password: ')
    password1 = input('Please re-enter your chosen password: ')
    if password == password1:
        password_checker(password)
    else:
        print('Please try again!')
        register()

    print('Creating your account!')
    with open('users.txt', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        csv_writer.writerow([username, password])

# Code here - Interactive loop
stop = False
while not stop:
    print('Welcome!\nTo view commands, please press Enter!')
    input()
    print("""COMMANDS
    Reset Login File [RLF]
    Register [R]
    Login    [L]
    Quit     [Q]
          """)
    choice = input('Select a Command: ')

    if choice == 'r':
        register()
    elif choice == 'rlf':
        reset_login_file()
    elif choice == 'l':
        login()
    elif choice == 'q':
        stop = True
    else:
    print('Choose a valid command')
```

---

Text from shell:

```
Welcome!  
To view commands, please press Enter!

COMMANDS  
    Reset Login File [RLF]  
    Register [R]  
    Login    [L]  
    Quit     [Q]  

Select a Command: r  
Please enter your chosen username: fred  
Name is taken, please try again!  
Please enter your chosen username: red  
Please enter your chosen password: bobsred  
Please re-enter your chosen password: bobsred  
Valid Password!  
Creating your account!  
Please enter your chosen password: redhead  
Please re-enter your chosen password: redhead  
Valid Password!  
Creating your account!  
Welcome!  
To view commands, please press Enter!
```

---

users.txt reads:

```
Admin,password  
bob,password  
fred,password  
red,bobsred  
fred,redhead
```

I would expect this to have register the user and then proceeded back to the interactive loop.

Comment: Could you show exactly what is the problem?

Comment: inside `register()` you run again `register()` when password is wrong - so when you set correct password then it returns from second `register()` to first `register()` and continue code in first `register()`. You should use `return register()` or use `while` loop instead of running again `register()`

Comment: You have several embedded calls to `register()`, so when you end up returning something at some point your program is running all the way back up the call stack. Password validation should only return `True` or `False` and password input should be in another while loop.

Comment: fixed code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the recursive calls to `register()` unwind and pick up where they left off.

One thing that would help is to design the helper functions  to return `True` if all is well, or `False` if the user needs to try again.  Then use loops inside `register()` to call them as many times as needed.

Here is an example:

```
# login.py
""" Logs in reading from a CSV
    text file
    """

# Imports
import csv

# Functions
def reset_login_file():
    """ Resets the users.txt
        file
        """

    with open('users.txt', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        csv_writer.writerow(['Admin', 'password'])

def login():
    """ Checks users.txt and
        logs in
        """

    print('')

def check_for_name(name_chosen):
    """ Checks for name_chosen in
        users.txt
        """

    with open('users.txt', 'r', newline='') as check_csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(check_csvfile)

        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[0] == name_chosen:
                print('Name is taken, please try again!')
                return False
    return True

def password_checker(password_chosen):
    """ Checks the password
        meets criteria
        """

    if len(password_chosen) > 6 and len(password_chosen) < 13:
        print('Valid Password!')
        return True
    else:
        print('Invalid Password, please try again!')
        return False

def register():
    """ Registers the user in
        users.txt
        """

    while True:
        username = input('Please enter your chosen username: ')
        if check_for_name(username):
            break
    while True:
        password = input('Please enter your chosen password: ')
        password1 = input('Please re-enter your chosen password: ')
        if password == password1:
            password_checker(password)
            break
        else:
            print('Please try again!')

    print('Creating your account!')
    with open('users.txt', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

        csv_writer.writerow([username, password])

# Code here - Interactive loop
stop = False
while not stop:
    print('Welcome!\nTo view commands, please press Enter!')
    input()
    print("""COMMANDS
    Reset Login File [RLF]
    Register [R]
    Login    [L]
    Quit     [Q]
          """)
    choice = input('Select a Command: ')

    if choice == 'r':
        register()
    elif choice == 'rlf':
        reset_login_file()
    elif choice == 'l':
        login()
    elif choice == 'q':
        stop = True
    else:
        print('Choose a valid command')
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't realise nesting the register() calls would cause it to pick up where each call left off. Returning True or False also helped me simplify the reading of the code.